# How to print to console from a CSV file after manipulating the data?

Tags: python, csv, console, export

I have a school project I am stuck on and can't figure out how to manipulate the data from a csv file and then print it to console in Python. Any help or pointing in the right direction would be very helpful.

In this assignment, you will read a csv data file `employees.csv`. The program should read the records in the file and produce a payroll report (on the screen).

[Sample picture of what output should look like in Python console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnRWD.jpg)

The payroll report is based on this information from a previous program. You should use (or reuse) functions to perform the following:

```
Compute the regular hours worked (40 hours and below)
Compute the overtime hours worked (those above 40 hours)
Compute the regular pay (regular hours times regular pay)
Compute the overtime pay (overtime hours times regular pay times 1.5)
Compute the gross pay
Compute the amount of federal tax withheld (12.4% of gross pay)
Compute the amount of state tax withheld (4.9% of gross pay)
Compute the amount of medicare withheld (1.4% of gross pay)
Compute the amount of social security withheld (6.2% of gross pay)
Compute the total deductions (federal tax + state tax + medicare + social security)
Compute the net pay (gross pay - deductions)
Print (to the screen) a clean summary report (see the output above)
```

Pull all of the above individual functions together in order, below the `def main()` and above the `main()` function call into one, clean, well-documented program. The program should have a `main()` function that calls all of the other functions.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this is not a good question for SO, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in particular [how do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I unfortunately don't have the time to read the novel you linked, however you are welcome to edit my question to follow what ever guidelines instilled.

Comment: Please respect the community of SO enough to read how to engage effectively. It's not about editing your question but you showing you've made an honest attempt at it - and where you are specifically getting stuck in your attempt. This is covered in the very first answer of the how do I ask and answer homework questions.

Comment: I understand, I already have a page of code written and nothing I type is manipulating the data from a csv file and printing appropriately to console. I did not ask for the whole answer just a push in the right direction and my question is specific to where I am stuck. I posted the assignment so someone with Python experience will know what I am trying to accomplish.